# Is it possible to access an iCloud document data across multiple apps (same id) or is it sandboxed?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, icloud

Had a simple question. With iCloud, if you create two apps, are you able to access the same iCloud document storage folder, if you have the luxury of having almost the same app id prefix etc, or is it sandboxed and restricted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. As a developer, you can configure iCloud entitlements across different apps such that they may utilize a 'shared' sandbox.

By setting the container identifier string to single key, different apps can use the same iCloud data.

See the documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html#/

Comment: Thanks wanted a quick answer whilst was at a meeting ( i know lazy but hope you earned a badge ). Thanks